# Do print() counts as a basic instruction?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, pseudocode

I'm counting the basic instructions of the following pseudocode:

```
algorithm double(n)
begin
  i = 1;            | 1 basic instruction (=)
  while i ≤ n do:   | 2 basic instruction (< and =) 
    i = i ∗ 2;      | 2 basic instruction (= and *) which "means" 2*n because the loop(?)
  print(i);         | 1 basic instruction (print)?
end
```

I count 3 basic instructions plus 2*n instructions from the while loop, so the number of basic instructions from the algorithm is 3 + 2n right?

Comment: "less than or equal to" is a single instruction.

Comment: How many times do you have to double `i` before it is larger than `n`?

Comment: "..., for n=3 i have to double i three times" -- what is the sequence of values `i` takes when n=3?

Comment: What do you think are the 3 instructions *not* part of the loop?  What are the 2 you think that *are*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: `print` would count as a basic instruction.

No: 3 + 2n is not right.